# android open message from a listview to an editext

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, message

I am trying to add the messages that are in the inbox on the listview and that is ok. I want to use the message to open it to a new edittext that is under of the listview.

here is my code

```
public List<String> getSMS() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
         String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
         String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
         sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body); 

      }
    return sms;
}
```

From this code I want to bring the String ''body'' and print it to a new Edittext. 
The question is how can I use the ''body'' variable outsite of the `getSMS()` method.
*the String 
body is the body of the message.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Message class with two data members :

```
public class Message {

  private String address;
  private String body;

  public Message( String address, String body ) {
      this.address = address;
      this.body = body;
  }

 public String getAddress() { 
    return address;
 }

 public String getBody() { 
    return body;
 }
```

}

then store your sms in a List instead of a List.

You will then obtain your messages piece by piece. Don't loose the information of classes, they hold independent properties and you should store them as such, don't mix them to early, let them available indepently and use objects for that.

Comment: i want one onitemclick to bring the body and to add it to an edittext wich is under of the listview

Comment: read some tutorial on how to display a list of something http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html. Your question is large. Number one of the job of a programmer is to cut big problems into small ones. Display a list, put an edit text in the footer, set up an action handling mechanism, get the message back, fill the edit text view.